# How to run electron app using Java and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, electron

I have a problem with running my Selenium tests on electron app.

I've added following options to ChromeOptions

```
 switch (driverType) {
            case CHROME:
                options = new ChromeOptions();
                ((ChromeOptions) options).setCapability("binary" , "path to exe file");
                ((ChromeOptions) options).setCapability("args" ,"path to folder where I have node_modules folder");
break;
```

When I open application on browser everything is OK, but when I try to open as Desktop App I get error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '4.0.0-beta-1', revision: '9c03156c2b'
```

Could someone get me a hint what else should I do?